# I am trying to use import and export in javascript but it is showing uncaught error. Here is the code :

Tags: javascript

my code :

```
const person = {
    name: 'Aish',
    age:21,
}

export default person;

error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at main.js:6:1)
```

Comment: this is ES6, nodejs works on common.js, you have to do it the `module.export` way or use a transpiler like babel

Comment: @Scriptkiddy1337 Or use a non-old version of NodeJS; it's been in there one way or another since Node 13.2 (?).

Comment: @Scriptkiddy1337 Nodejs actual version fully supports ES Modules without need to transpile, you just have to use the correct module extension to tell it that you are using ES modules and not CJS modules.

Comment: I'm sorry, thank you, I really didn't knew.

Answer (score 1):

Change script extensions to .mjs, or add an entry to *package.json*: `"type" : "module"` .

> *Node.js fully supports ECMAScript modules as they are currently specified and provides interoperability between them and its original module format, CommonJS.
>
> ***Enabling#*** 
> Node.js has two module systems: CommonJS modules and
> ECMAScript modules.
>
> Authors can tell Node.js to use the ECMAScript modules loader via the
> .mjs file extension, the package.json "type" field, or the
> --input-type flag. Outside of those cases, Node.js will use the CommonJS module loader. See Determining module system for more
> details.**

[Source](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using ES6 import/export but the environment you're working on is using commonjs

for **Node.js**

go to your package.json and set the `type` entry as `"module"`

example:

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

Note: make sure to update your nodejs to latest version

for **Browser**

in your script tag add `type='module'` as an attribute

example:

```html
<script src="./index.js" type="module" defer></script>
```